# iOS Outline of Stroked UIBezierPath/CGPath, as a Path

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, uibezierpath, cgpath

(I have read other answers on SO, but they do not appear to address the problem at hand.)

[Swift 4, Xcode 9]

I need to get the path representing the drawn areas following the `stroke()` of a path. i.e. a path that represents the outline of the stroke.

Given a `UIBezierPath` with the following attributes:

```
let dotWidth: CGFloat = 3
let spacing: CGFloat = 12
let dashes: [CGFloat] = [0.0, spacing]
let lineCapStyle: CGLineCap = .round
let lineJoinStyle: CGLineJoin = .miter
bezierPath.lineCapStyle = lineCapStyle
bezierPath.lineJoinStyle = lineJoinStyle
bezierPath.setLineDash(dashes, count: dashes.count, phase: 0)
bezierPath.lineWidth = dotWidth
```

Xcode's debugger preview will kindly render the result:

[image]

**I need those dots as a path.**

First attempt, using the modern version of `CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath()`

```
let strokedCGPath = bezierPath.cgPath.copy(strokingWithWidth: dotWidth,
    lineCap: lineCapStyle,
    lineJoin: lineJoinStyle,
    miterLimit: 4)
```

[image]

Second attempt:

```
let dashedCGPath = bezierPath.cgPath.copy(dashingWithPhase: 0, lengths: dashes)
```

[image]

Result: neither `copy(strokingWithWidth:)` or `copy(dashingWithPhase:)` give me the complete path that I need.

**Question**: am I missing something obvious here? Is there a way to get the entire path of the stroke?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

[EDITED]

My previous answer was incorrect.

Using CGPath's `copy(dashingWithPhase: phase, lengths: pattern)` will not work in this situation. Despite the method's description, it will not actually produce a *full* outline path of the resulting stroke.

A working solution is:

- create a temporary `CGContext`
- on the context, set all the stroke-related parameters such as `lineCap`, `lineWidth`, `lineJoin` and most importantly, `lineDash`
- add your path to the context: `context.addPath(bezierPath.cgPath)`
- do NOT call `fill()` or `stroke()`. We are not interested in drawing.
- instead, call `context.replacePathWithStrokedPath()`
- finally, pull a new cgPath out of the context with `let newCGPath = context.path`

This `newCGPath` will be the outline of the stroked path, as if it had been drawn.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer!

Comment: This was fantastic and solved exactly my problem!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could also combine the two. Should provide the effect you are after.

```
let dashedCGPath = bezierPath.cgPath
    .copy(dashingWithPhase: 0, lengths: dashes)
    .copy(strokingWithWidth: dotWidth, lineCap: lineCapStyle, lineJoin: lineJoinStyle, miterLimit: 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there are two different algorithms discussed here, let me show the difference:

```
cgPath.copy(dashingWithPhase: phase, lengths: pattern)
```

creates one-dimensional polylines as subpaths that are *not* closed for each dash. They do not contain a `closeSubpath` element. "strokes"

on the other hand

```
context.replacePathWithStrokedPath()
let newCGPath = context.path
```

creates two-dimensional closed polygons as subpaths for each dash. They do contain a `closeSubpath` element.  "shapes"

Hope this helps to choose the algorithm they need.